# Is window.addEventListener("load",function() faster than <script> placed on bottom of page?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I have a simple Javascript function that can be placed anywhere within HTML document. So I put it right below the closing , for example:

```
<html>
<body>
Some text.
<script>
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML='hello';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is - would it make sense (from page load speed point of view) to load this script via the addEventListener("load") function instead? Ie. if I use this code below - which would be preferred? I understand that when Javascript is on the bottom of the page, it won't 'block' page rendering anyway, so using the addEventListener may only slow the execution down?

```
<html>
<body>
Some text.
<script>
window.addEventListener("load",function()
{document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML='hello';},
false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's no practical difference between these, other than the inherent fact that "load" doesn't fire until all the page artifacts have loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Scripts should generally not be placed directly in the HTML like that, because they *block* further HTML parsing until they're executed. While it's not a problem if you have only one script, what if you have two, or three, or more, and some of them might take more than a handful of ms to parse?

Still, assuming that blocking isn't an issue, there's no real difference on way or the other, from the UX point of view.

Scripts, being information about how to *interact* with the content, but aren't actually content themselves, belong in the `<head>` IMO. If you don't like wrapping everything in a `load` listener, you can use the `defer` attribute to automatically run the script once the whole HTML has been parsed: `<script src="..." defer>`.